# error after build in react native for ios

Tags: reactjs, react-native, build, react-native-ios, ipa

Command for build **.ipa** (.app) file:

```
react-native run-ios --configuration=release
```

And I want to build app for ios, but cant uploaded to diawi, console error:

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

Installing build/Build/Products/release-iphonesimulator/app.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Launching org.reactjs.native.example.app
org.reactjs.native.example.app: 11067
```

Error in Diawi (the .app file itself exists):

> An error occurred: 4001009: Invalid .ipa file: missing embedded
>   mobileprovision

What I should do? Worked on simulator. Maybe somehow on another can build?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check main three steps from **xCode**:

1. Set proper Bundle Indentifier
2. Select Team from which you created your certificate and provisional profile
3. Set your Signing Developer.

[image: Check Ref]